# Data not fetched from web servers

Tags: android, api, http-headers, retrofit, httpsurlconnection

I have been trying to make an app which fetches data about etymology from the oxford dictionary app. On trying to use retrofit, to get data, onFailiure() is always called. I will be uploading my code and also the correct code but the one which uses HttpsURLConnection instead for reference.

I thought that the app_key and app_id aren't sent to the server properly and so I tried to send these in various ways. First way to add @Headers tag

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json","app_id: ********","app_key: ******************"})
```

I also tried an interceptor to add header.

```
@Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request newRequest;

        newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader(Accept,"application/json").addHeader(app_id,"*******").addHeader(app_key,"**********")
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
```

and then adding client to retrofit.

But all of these returned the same error.

Here is my code using retrofit.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GetDataInterface INTERFACE;
    WordDetails wordclass;
    TextView temp;
    final String app_id = "*********";
    final String app_key = "***************";
    final String theword = "chaos";
    final String word_id = theword.toLowerCase();
    final String TheAdd = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/en-gb/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        temp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temp);
        wordclass = new WordDetails();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/en-gb/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        INTERFACE = retrofit.create(GetDataInterface.class);
        Call<WordDetails> call = INTERFACE.getData(word_id,"etymologies","false");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<WordDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WordDetails> call, Response<WordDetails> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    System.out.println("Server Error.");
                    return;
                }
                wordclass = new WordDetails();
                wordclass=response.body();

                if(wordclass.getResults().getLexicalEntries().getEntries().getEtymologies()!=null)
                {
                    temp.setText(wordclass.getResults().getLexicalEntries().getEntries().getEtymologies());
                }
                else
                    temp.setText("ERROR");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WordDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failed to fetch.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Throwable throws

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 8 column 17 path $.results
```

GetDataInterface.java

```
public interface GetDataInterface {

    final String app_id = "*********";
    final String app_key = "************";
    final String Accept = "application/json";

    @Headers({"Accept: "+Accept,"app_id: "+app_id,"app_key: "+app_key})
    @GET("{id}")
    Call<WordDetails> getData(@Path("id") String Sambhar, @Query("fields") String Mirchi, @Query("strictMatch") String Trichy);
}
```

WordDetails.java

```
public class WordDetails {
    Results results;

    public Results getResults()
    {
        return results;
    }
    public WordDetails()
    {
        results = new Results();
    }

    class Results
    {
        Lexical lexicalEntries;
        public Results()
        {
            lexicalEntries = new Lexical();
        }
        public Lexical getLexicalEntries() {
            return lexicalEntries;
        }

        class Lexical
        {
            Entries entries;
            public Lexical()
            {
                entries = new Entries();
            }
            public Entries getEntries() {
                return entries;
            }

            class Entries
            {
                String etymologies;
                public Entries()
                {
                    etymologies="";
                }
                public String getEtymologies() {
                    return etymologies;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat for this is

```
2019-07-04 16:45:25.872 22520-22616/? I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2019-07-04 16:45:25.879 22520-22616/? I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2019-07-04 16:45:25.884 22520-22616/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-07-04 16:45:25.885 22520-22616/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-07-04 16:45:25.885 22520-22616/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-07-04 16:45:25.885 22520-22616/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-07-04 16:45:26.955 22520-22614/com.example.spidertask3_v2 W/.spidertask3_v: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-07-04 16:45:28.677 22520-22614/com.example.spidertask3_v2 W/.spidertask3_v: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
2019-07-04 16:45:29.121 22520-22520/com.example.spidertask3_v2 I/System.out: Failed to fetch. com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 8 column 17 path $.results
```

The sample data is of the following form

```
{
  "metadata": {},
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "language": "string",
      "lexicalEntries": [
        {
          "derivativeOf": [
            {
              "domains": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "id": "string",
              "language": "string",
              "regions": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "registers": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "text": "string"
            }
          ],
          "derivatives": [
            {
              "domains": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "id": "string",
              "language": "string",
              "regions": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "registers": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "text": "string"
            }
          ],
          "entries": [
            {
              "etymologies": [
                "string"
              ],
              "grammaticalFeatures": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ],
              "homographNumber": "string",
              "notes": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ],
              "pronunciations": [
                {
                  "audioFile": "string",
                  "dialects": [
                    "string"
                  ],
                  "phoneticNotation": "string",
                  "phoneticSpelling": "string",
                  "regions": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "senses": [
                {
                  "crossReferenceMarkers": [
                    "string"
                  ],
                  "crossReferences": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "definitions": [
                    "string"
                  ],
                  "domains": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "examples": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "string"
                      ],
                      "domains": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "notes": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string",
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "regions": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "registers": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "senseIds": [
                        "string"
                      ],
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "string",
                  "notes": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "pronunciations": [
                    {
                      "audioFile": "string",
                      "dialects": [
                        "string"
                      ],
                      "phoneticNotation": "string",
                      "phoneticSpelling": "string",
                      "regions": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "regions": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "registers": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "string"
                  ],
                  "subsenses": [
                    {}
                  ],
                  "thesaurusLinks": [
                    {
                      "entry_id": "string",
                      "sense_id": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "variantForms": [
                    {
                      "domains": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "notes": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string",
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "pronunciations": [
                        {
                          "audioFile": "string",
                          "dialects": [
                            "string"
                          ],
                          "phoneticNotation": "string",
                          "phoneticSpelling": "string",
                          "regions": [
                            {
                              "id": "string",
                              "text": "string"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "regions": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "registers": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "variantForms": [
                {
                  "domains": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "notes": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "pronunciations": [
                    {
                      "audioFile": "string",
                      "dialects": [
                        "string"
                      ],
                      "phoneticNotation": "string",
                      "phoneticSpelling": "string",
                      "regions": [
                        {
                          "id": "string",
                          "text": "string"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "regions": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "registers": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "grammaticalFeatures": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "text": "string",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "language": "string",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "string",
            "text": "string"
          },
          "notes": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "text": "string",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "pronunciations": [
            {
              "audioFile": "string",
              "dialects": [
                "string"
              ],
              "phoneticNotation": "string",
              "phoneticSpelling": "string",
              "regions": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "text": "string",
          "variantForms": [
            {
              "domains": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "notes": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ],
              "pronunciations": [
                {
                  "audioFile": "string",
                  "dialects": [
                    "string"
                  ],
                  "phoneticNotation": "string",
                  "phoneticSpelling": "string",
                  "regions": [
                    {
                      "id": "string",
                      "text": "string"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "regions": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "registers": [
                {
                  "id": "string",
                  "text": "string"
                }
              ],
              "text": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "pronunciations": [
        {
          "audioFile": "string",
          "dialects": [
            "string"
          ],
          "phoneticNotation": "string",
          "phoneticSpelling": "string",
          "regions": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "text": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "type": "string",
      "word": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the one using HttpsURLConnection and which works well. (for reference to help me with the retrofit code)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TEMP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEMP);

    new CallbackTask().execute(dictionaryEntries());
}

private String dictionaryEntries() {
    final String language = "en-gb";
    final String word = "chaos";
    final String fields = "etymologies";
    final String strictMatch = "false";
    final String word_id = word.toLowerCase();
    return "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/" + language + "/" + word_id + "?" + "fields=" + fields + "&strictMatch=" + strictMatch;
}


private class CallbackTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        final String app_id = "********";
        final String app_key = "******************";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_id",app_id);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_key",app_key);

            // read the output from the server
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        TEMP.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Output for this as an app is something like https://ibb.co/0FCtG21

I would want to have the data (etymology of chaos) to be shown in the textview using retrofit. HttpsURLConnection is for reference to show the nature of oxford api.

Comment: Dont expose your keys like that

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh ya sure I'll just edit that. Thanks

Comment: You need your interceptor with correct authentication values.
and in your `onFailure()` you can append the `t` to output so you can see what the error is. Consider using http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ to see output and response.

Comment: Thanks for that @VonSchnauzer . I have edited the question with the throwable. I'll try to solve the issue.

Comment: can you share your logcat here?

Comment: @Prince Edited in the question details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my WordDetails.class was wrong. All the variables had to be in the form of list.

```
public class WordDetails {
    List<Results> results;

    public List<Results> getResults()
    {
        return results;
    }

    class Results
    {
        List<Lexical> lexicalEntries;
        public List<Lexical> getLexicalEntries() {
            return lexicalEntries;
        }

        class Lexical
        {
            List<Entries> entries;
            public List<Entries> getEntries() {
                return entries;
            }

            class Entries
            {
                List<String> etymologies;
                public List<String> getEtymologies() {
                    return etymologies;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```